# Term to describe the movement in a group of maggots?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am a non-native speaker.

What would one call the movement of a large group of vermin (not of an individual)?

For instance, picture a huddle of maggots in cat food. How are they moving?

`Creeping` or `crawling` came to my mind, but this rather describes the way of moving of a single maggot rather than the chaotic movement of the group.

Comment: "Writhing" is the first word that comes to mind.

Comment: If you look at them individually and close up (which few people care to do) I think you'll see that the maggots are actually intermittently _squirming_, _twitching_, and _undulating_.

Comment: Unclear - too many different kinds of "*vermin*", which move differently. See the answers given so far. Pick a kind of vermin and you will get a reasonable answer. If not, there is unlikely to be a word that fits all of the types. Maggots and bees don't *scurry*...

Comment: Eww. Just... eww.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Crawling](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=alive+with+maggots%2Ccrawling+with+maggots&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calive%20with%20maggots%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrawling%20with%20maggots%3B%2Cc0) can actually be used to describe the chaotic movement of a group of vermin, as in "the old cheese was [crawling](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/be-crawling-with) with maggots."

**be crawling with**: to be full or completely covered with people, insects, or animals, in a way that is unpleasant.

[Be alive with](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+alive+with) is another idiom that might fit the bill.

*The cat food was [alive with maggots](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=alive+with+maggots&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calive%20with%20maggots%3B%2Cc0).*

**be alive with**: to be covered or full of something that is moving

Alternately, consider [wriggle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wriggle) and **squirm**.

*Maggots were [wriggling](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=maggots+squirming%2Cmaggots+wriggling&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmaggots%20squirming%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmaggots%20wriggling%3B%2Cc0) all over the cat food*.

**wriggle**: to twist from side to side with small quick movements like a worm

Comment: wriggle and squirm yes

Comment: Does that improve the quality of the cat food from the cat's perspective?

Comment: @simbabque You bet it does! Makes it a lot richer in protein.

Comment: @Elian I've always wondered about this.  Wouldn't the protein in the maggots just be the protein that they extracted from the cat food they were writhing around in and eating?  I might have to ask biology.se...

Answer (score 7):

The cat food is [teeming](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/teeming) with maggots.

Teem: be full of or swarming with.

Comment: Teem is an excellent word, +1. But it tends to be used in a neutral or positive sense, and doesn't convey any disgust about the maggots. Writhing sounds more unpleasant, but of course, it could apply to one individual.

Answer (score 6):

In the particular case of maggots in cat food, the following come to mind:

The maggots were _____

-writhing,
-churning

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest the maggots, rats, fleas, or whatever might *[swarm](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/swarm)*:-

> To move or gather in large numbers [American Heritage Dictionary via the Free Dictionary]

or perhaps *[overrun](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overrun)*:-

> To spread or swarm over destructively [American Heritage Dictionary via the Free Dictionary]

So you might say *the maggots swarmed over the cat food* or *the rats overran the kitchen*.

Comment: flying insects can swarm. I'd extend that to rats and fleas. But maggots move too slowly to be described as swarming for me.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is **skittering**, though this may only apply to larger vermin, such as rats or large insects (think Temple of Doom).  **Slithering** also works for worm- or snake-like critters.  Maybe not maggots specifically.

Comment: I like skittering - this works for almost everything (not worms).

Answer (score 4):

**[seethe](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seething)**

> 2. Constantly moving or active: Agitated

It's common enough that "seething maggots" gets a ranking in [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seething%20maggots&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseething%20maggots%3B%2Cc0). [Example of use](https://books.google.com/books?id=qh5EAQAAIAAJ&q=%22seething%20maggots%22&dq=%22seething%20maggots%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAjgUahUKEwjV6OeO4ZzIAhXFfYgKHXwbDbQ):

> What they found was not a pleasant sight: rotting carcasses covered in
>   a white cream of seething maggots...

Answer (score 3):

The word "vermin" made me think of rodents or other small animals, rather than maggots, and the word that comes to mind to describe their movements is **scurry**.